# issue with .net assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly

I have created some class A.cs whose function is to be used in B.cs then B.cs is called in ASP.net webforms in codebehind. My files A.cs and B.cs is kept in App_Code folder.

The issue is if i call the function of B.cs in asp.net webform codebehind i get error that function is not defind are you missing an assembly? After researching on SO, i found to make class build action to compile. Though it solved the issue, but when i build the app i got error that my assembly is present in root as app_code and assembly.dll both

Then i reverted the process, and got same function not found issue.

I am seriously unable to figure out,How to solve this???

Comment: sorry for not writing exact class name and writing a.cs and b.cs, as the name was too long.

Comment: please post exact error messages.

Comment: The error message is.                                                               CS0433: The type 'Gal.DB.Service' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d8160213\56a9c14e\App_Code.caoxa36k.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d8160213\56a9c14e\assembly\dl3\6adab08f\f023d463_4f03ce01\Gal.DB.Manager.DLL'

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have defined the `Gal.DB.Service` class in both the ASP.NET web app (under `App_Code`) *and* in an assembly that the web app references (i.e. `Gal.DB.Manager.DLL`).

The class can only be defined once.

Comment: J0e3gan I have not referenced any assembly. The issue was my classes A.cs B.cs had to be instantiated to call its object in a webform. At compile time if im not changing the debug of class to compile, I cant instantiate the class as it is not known to webform what that class is at compile time giving me compiletime error.

As soon as i did that my compile time error was gone but it created a new issue and that was my those class after compilation created a new class assembly that was interfering with the App_Code classes present in App_Code folder.

Comment: I asked this to Ray Cheng, and as he suggested at compilation, my classes were not creating a assembly now on run, but new issue created was My webform was not able to recognize the class in App_Code

Answer (score 1):

I run into this exact problem before. The way I fixed it is moving all the code files form `App_Code` folder to a `Classes` folder (or any folder of your choice) and then compile and fix the compiling errors. After, the  error went away.

Comment: Yup that did fixed the problem. But I ran into a new issue, can i ask here, or it is against community rules to ask something which is new in new thread. I want to ask it here just because it is related to assembly?

Comment: I suppose you can ask here because your original title is not specific. But after your issues are resolved, I think the title needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

try clearing the temporary asp.net files, depending on what web server you are using, you'll want to stop, reset or kill it to release the files before deleting them.

It sounds like this is a web app, where asp.net makes its best guess about what needs to be compiled. If this compilation model causes too much trouble, web project might be easier in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Matthew I accepted your answer and tried doing both still no gain.

Comment: MatthewMartin: Thanks Sir, but I tried that before pasting this que on SO, It didn't help. I need something to brick this issue.

Comment: I don't understand. You said that Ray Cheng answered your question. If your initial question has been answered, mark Ray's as correct and create a new question.  In any case, if you have a new error message, you need to post the new error message, it serves no one to speculate on what error message you might be viewing.